# GoldMine CRM double-click to call

Tags: c#, dde, goldmine

I am currently developing a simple TAPI application in C# that will be integrated into GoldMine CRM, to replace a current application that we have.

One of the functions that I am currently facing issues with is their "Click to Call" function, which allows the user to directly ring the number field that has been double-clicked.

Upon further investigation, I have found that the current application is fired up from the USER.ini file, in the [Modem] section. Within the [Modem] section, there are 4 DDEDial sections; outlining the path to the application (C:\Projects\TestCommunicator\TestCommunicator.exe). The paths for all 4 can be the same.

I have since replaced mine with that of the new Communicator which I have built. However, the application does not fire up. I have replicated the process in CMD and it works perfectly fine; even calling up the number.

Has anyone here had the experience of dealing with GoldMine's DDEDial module? Thanks.

ps: I will update this post tomorrow with code snippets as I'm done for the day. :)

Comment: "I will update this post tomorrow with code snippets as I'm done for the day." Long hard day? Did you resolve this? I'm a bit curious, as I'm also working on a "click to call" program, but my problem is more how to capture the telephone number that the user has clicked on.

Comment: Hi @RenniePet, yes I did eventually. Are you using Goldmine too? What was your problem?

Comment: No, my current problems with "click to call" are quite unrelated to your problems, it's just that this thread showed up on a search for "click to call C#", and my silly sense of humor inspired my comment. (I'm trying to implement a click to call that will work for any telephone number the user sees on his/her screen, in a browser window, a Word document, an email, anywhere, via a global Windows hot key. Not even sure if it's possible.)